# How to disable text field or input if a value is present?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to pull the value(which works) and disable the field from input(which will NOT work) and post it. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code below:

```
<textarea name="title" id="title"><?php
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$member'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $member = mysql_real_escape_string($member);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo $title;
    }?> <?=($disable ? " disabled=\"disabled\"" : "");?>
    <?php if($title == true) {
    $disable = true;
    }
    else {
    $disable = false;
    }
    ?></textarea>
```

Comment: @Brion, don't do a `select *`, if you only need field title. Do `select title from table ...`. Doing select * if you do not need **all** the fields slows your code down for no reason. Oh and don't forget to escape `$member` by doing `$member = mysql_real_escape_string($member);` to prevent SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: +1 for a good tip, most of the beginners (even me when I started learning) do these kind of mistakes.

Comment: @Johan Hey Thanks. Any ideas on how to disable the text field?

Comment: @Johan I do have other text fields in this form do you recommend no select * for all fields?

Comment: @Brion, I mean: do not do `select *`. Makes the code slow. Do `select field1, field2, field3 from ...` if you need field1, field2 and field3. This makes your code faster. **Only you know which fields you need for your form**

Comment: @Brion, q1: I'm not a php expert, just MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're trying to disable it based on query results (which it looks like what you're trying to do). You're closing the `textarea` opening tag *before* setting the disabled attribute. The `disabled` attribute has to be an attribute of the `textarea` tag:

`<textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>`

Comment: I am trying to disable based on query results. I changed the the code around and its still enabled.

Comment: Injecting HTML code via PHP can be confusing for beginners. This PHP code is just slightly misplaced.

Comment: @brion: when you view the html output of the page, do you see something to the effect of `<textarea id="title" name="title" disabled="disabled">`?

Comment: Sorry, it worked! I have rich text field on that field which does not work with that code. When i disabled the rich text field it works. I'm using CKEDITOR.